# Datalab occasionally very slow on simple tasks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-datalab

I've noticed that datalab is occasionally extremely slow (to the point where I believe it's just hanging).

```
import json
import pprint
import subprocess
import pyspark
```

For instance, on this really trivial code block, the code takes forever to train. If I keep trying to refresh the page and run it, sometimes it works. What can cause this?

Comment: Any number of reasons can cause this, we need more context. Are you running Datalab on a VM? Is the machine busy doing something else? Can you browse files and do other operations normally or are those also slow?

Comment: I found out the reason was that I thought I had interrupted or restarted the notebook when I had not. This was fixed by repeatedly pressing the interrupt option on datalab.

Answer (score 1):

Resize your VM or create a new one with a larger memory/CPUs. You can do this by stopping the VM and then editing it in Compute Engine.